# how to call a Ajax control event from jQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I am working with some controls that are written using microsoft ajax tool kit. I want to trigger an event in these controls using jQuery. I was hoping that it should be as simple as triggering any event from jQuery but it does not seem to be working. Here is sample code..

Ajax Control

```
/// <reference name="MicrosoftAjax.js"/>

Type.registerNamespace("MyNameSpace");

MyNameSpace.AjaxUserControl = function(element) {
  MyNameSpace.AjaxUserControl.initializeBase(this, [element]);
}

MyNameSpace.AjaxUserControl.prototype = {
  initialize: function() {
  MyNameSpace.AjaxUserControl.callBaseMethod(this, 'initialize');
  }
},

dispose: function() {

  MyNameSpace.AjaxUserControl.callBaseMethod(this, 'dispose');
},

_onChange: function(evt) {
  alert('On Change event.');
  },
}
if (typeof(Sys) !== 'undefined') Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded();
```

Jquery Code:

```
var myJqueryControl = (function ($, AjaxControl) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var ajaxEventProxy = Function.createDelegate(AjaxControl, AjaxControl._onChange);
  $("#JqueryCommandButton").click(ajaxEventProxy);
} (jQuery,MyNameSpace.AjaxUserControl));
```

Its not working, when the button is clicked i cannot see alert message inside onchange. Would appreciate any guidance on how to make it work.

Thanks
CSC

Comment: stop using microsoft's lame ajax library and the ajax control toolkit! :)

Comment: I am trying to.. i don't like it but have to support old code :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would work much easier if you followed the [JQuery widget pattern](http://bililite.com/blog/understanding-jquery-ui-widgets-a-tutorial/).  Because an AJAX control wraps around an element, much like the widget does, you can more easily integrate the two, by writing some setup with the init method:

```
_init: function() {
    //store a control reference within the widget
    this._control = $find(this.element.attr("id"));
}
```

Then, in your widget, you can refer to the control via the `this._control`.

If you can't switch models, the way to resolve this is not refer to the type directly, but the instance... instead of passing in the reference `MyNameSpace.AjaxUserControl` to the constructor, pass in an instance, then you can do:

```
instance._onchange();
```

To invoke the event.

Comment: Thanks a ton Brian. Very informative. I will try your recommendations. Thanks again.